# "Технология", "техника", "методика" - в чем отличие?

Tags: значение-слов

Чем меж собою отличаются понятия "техника", "технология" и "методика"? Эти слова означают сложившиеся алгоритмы, последовательности действий, инструкции по осуществлению какой-либо нацеленной деятельности.

Мои предположения. Технология описывает процессы создания каких-либо вещей, методика - иные процессы, не связанные с обогащением искусственной среды (обучение, ведение переговоров и т. п.) Ведь невозможны же "методики создания мебельных изделий", а только технологии. Хотя вот "технологии ведения переговоров, обучения" вполне допустимы, однако, кажется, они предполагают использование некоторых материальных средств (компьютеров при обучении, доски, экрана и т д). "Техника" же характеризует индивидуальные умения, разработки (техника горной выработки - умения отдельных лиц, участвующих в этом).

Answer (score 1):

Предположения верные.

Техника - совокупность профессиональных приёмов, используемых в каком-либо деле, искусстве; владение такими приёмами, мастерство в каком-либо деле. Например: *техника игры на музыкальном инструменте, композиторская техника*.

Технология - совокупность методов, процессов и средств, используемых при производстве, изготовлении чего-либо.

Методика - совокупность методов, приёмов практического выполнения чего-либо.

Comment: Технология и техника соотносятся приблизительно, как стратегия и тактика?

Comment: В принципе да. Технология и тактика соотносятся - как совокупность методов, приёмов. Стратегия и техника соотносятся - как искусство ведения войны / какой-то деятельности.

Comment: Я имел в виду, что стратегия и технология - как долгосрочное описание, планирование всей деятельности в целом со всеми её составляющими, а тактика и техника - как конкретное приложение отдельных пунктов стратегии (технологии).

Comment: Да, и такая связь есть. Если анализировать понятия, можно найти много соотношений. Только что технология относится к производству и политике, а стратегия - к любой деятельности.